# Azure agent: where to find SqlPackage.exe

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sqlpackage

I use a Microsoft hosted agent for building and verifying my project including an sql project.

On this azure agent I need to find the `SqlPackage.exe` file to call it via a powershell task. I know that there is the `SqlServerDacpacDeployment` task but that does not satisfy my needs. I also know that the `SqlPackage.exe` has to be somewhere because the `SqlServerDacpacDeployment` task can run without the failure that it can not find the `SqlPackage.exe` file.

Does anybody know where it is installed on an agent with `vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'` or how to located it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For `VS2017-Win2016` agent:**

You can find the `SqlPackage.exe` under path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150\`

This is also the installation path in local machine. For devops, you can use [CMD task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) with content below to check whether the `SqlPackage.exe` exists there:

```
C:
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150\
dir
```

Check the log and you'll find:

[image]

And for Windows-2019, just use `2019` instead of `2017` in the path above.